# CSS - How to show full opacity of image when clicked?

Tags: hover, transition, fade, effect

I want to let my visitors select from 3 images and once when they hover over the images they the full opacity will faded in, once they've clicked an image the full opacity should be displayed.

All I can find on Google is how to change opacity on hover but not how to change opacity when an image has been clicked.

Comment: you'd need to use javascript to initiate the change upon the click event happening

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me a code perhaps?

Comment: Using **javascript** you can change the style(opacity) of the image back to original, on a onclick event

Comment: Thanks, do you have a jsfiddle example for me please?

Comment: Google `onclick` javascript or jquery events + opacity to first find out how to code the event  and then find out how to use that code to change the opacity value.

Comment: If I tell you how to do it you won't learn anything :-p

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6y3gcnj2/4/)